# Graduation in/from/at

Tags: grammar, prepositions

I read this sentence somewhere

> After his graduation in the field of medicine at Harvard University, he was offered a great job.

Is this sentence grammatically correct?
Aren't we supposed to use the preposition **from** instead of **at** and say:

> After his graduation in the field of medicine from Harvard University, he was offered a great job

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the second example is better. The difference becomes more striking if you omit the phrase "in the field of medicine": "His graduation at Harvard" might make sense only for the graduation *ceremony*, which could be said to occur "at" Harvard. Perhaps the author became distracted by the "field of medicine" phrase, which might have suggested "He studied medicine *at* Harvard."